# Bash - How to execute a script which is output from a different script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, exec, eval

I have a CLI which generates a bash script. How can I evaluate it immediatly without redirecting to a .sh file?

example is to change the following:

```
~: toolWhichGeneratesScript > tmp.sh
~: chmod +x tmp.sh
~: ./tmp.sh
```

to something like:

```
~: toolWhichGeneratesScript | evaluate
```

Comment: Thanks all for the very FAST answers. Embarrassed that I didn't think of that! Whose answer should I except???

Comment: I would accept the one suggested by @thatotherguy because it's the most flexible solution, unless your `toolWhichGeneratesScript` might create a *very* long script, in which case the other ones are safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in commands to run with `bash -c` (or `sh -c`):

```
bash -c "$(toolWhichGeneratesScript)"
```

> ```
>    -c        If the -c option is present, then  commands
>              are read from the first non-option argument
>              command_string.   If  there  are  arguments
>              after the command_string, they are assigned
>              to the positional parameters, starting with
>              $0.
> ```

Unlike piping to the shell, this leaves stdin free for you to interact with prompts and programs the script runs.

Answer (score 1):

The shell reads its script from standard input:

```
toolWhichGeneratesScript | sh
```

(In fact, an interactive shell does the same; it's standard input just happens to be a terminal.)

Note that you need to know *which* shell to use; if your tool outputs `bash` extensions, then you have to pipe it to `bash`. Also, if the generated script itself needs to read from standard input, you have a bit of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this : toolWhichGeneratesScript | bash